# need brute force, divide and conquer, dynamic programming and greedy algorithms for matrix inversion?

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming, linear-algebra, greedy

I need different algorithms that use different approaches like brute force, divide and conquer, dynamic programming and greedy algorithms for matrix inversion. It would be very helpful if I get one algorithm per approach.Because I need to compare all four algorithms and find which one is efficient in terms of time complexity and space complexity.

I tried finding them online but found algorithms that use different methods like Gauss Jordan method, adjoint method to find inverse of a matrix. But I couldn't categorize them into approaches like dp or greedy.